# jQuery ignore elements inline block on .fadeOut

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css, fadeout

So what I have is 3 divs inline-block. when an image inside of any of the divs is clicked, the other divs fade out & the div with the 'clicked' image in it slides to the left. I've got the center div working perfectly, however when I click the furthest right image (which fades out the center div & left div) the right div animates & then jumps (as though it moved to the center of the page before it animates) I know exactly why it's doing this. I'm just stuck with remedying it!

HTML :

```
<div id = "cicontainer">
            <div id = "facebook">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img id = "facebookimg" src = "facebook.png" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3> Facebook </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei option sapientem his, vide mucius fuisset mea id. Te novum consulatu nam, vim cu postea delectus. Nam an zril aliquando signiferumque, ea sea volutpat definitiones. Vis ut dicat ludus.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id = "mail">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img id ="mailimg" src = "mail.png" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3> Email </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei option sapientem his, vide mucius fuisset mea id. Te novum consulatu nam, vim cu postea delectus. Nam an zril aliquando signiferumque, ea sea volutpat definitiones. Vis ut dicat ludus.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>          
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id = "phone">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img id = "phoneimg" src = "phone.png" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3> Phone </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei option sapientem his, vide mucius fuisset mea id. Te novum consulatu nam, vim cu postea delectus. Nam an zril aliquando signiferumque, ea sea volutpat definitiones. Vis ut dicat ludus.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

         </div>
```

CSS:

```
#cicontainer    {
height: 556px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;

}

#facebook   {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
position: relative;
}

#mail   {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
position: relative;
}

#phone  {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
position: relative;
}

#cicontainer h3 {
margin-top: 50px;
font-family: BonvenoCF-Light;
}

#cicontainer p  {
font-family: BonvenoCF-Light;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#facebookimg').click(function(){
    $('#mail').fadeOut(1500);
    $('#phone').fadeOut(1500);
    });

$('#mailimg').click(function(){
    $('#facebook').fadeOut(1500);
    $('#phone').fadeOut(1500);
    $('#mail').animate({
        left: '-=292' }, 1500, function(){
        });
    });

    $('#phoneimg').click(function(){
    $('#mail').fadeOut(1500);
    $('#facebook').fadeOut(1500);
     $('#phone').animate({
        left: '-=584' }, 1500, function(){

        });
    });
});
```

This is how the code works at present, I've tried numerous ways to fix it. But I'm sure there is a much simpler (cleaner way).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fadeOut function basically animates the opacity of the element to 0, then changes it's display to 'none', affecting in turn the layout of the elements. I  suppose this is making your right-most element jump. Try replacing the fadeOut() in `$('#phoneimg").click` with

```
animate({opacity:0})
```

Comment: thank you so much! I was initially trying to remedy this by using the .css('opacity' , '0') but it didn't work correctly! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to look like following:

CSS

```
            #cicontainer    {
height: 556px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 50px;

}

.block{
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
position: absolute;
}

#facebook   {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
left:100;
}

#mail   {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
left: 332px;
}

#phone  {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width: 202px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 30px;
left: 564px;
}

#cicontainer h3 {
margin-top: 50px;
font-family: BonvenoCF-Light;
}

#cicontainer p  {
font-family: BonvenoCF-Light;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id = "cicontainer">
            <div class="block" id = "facebook">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img class="handle" id = "facebookimg" src = "facebook.png" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3> Facebook </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei option sapientem his, vide mucius fuisset mea id. Te novum consulatu nam, vim cu postea delectus. Nam an zril aliquando signiferumque, ea sea volutpat definitiones. Vis ut dicat ludus.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="block" id = "mail">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img class="handle" id ="mailimg" src = "mail.png" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3> Email </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei option sapientem his, vide mucius fuisset mea id. Te novum consulatu nam, vim cu postea delectus. Nam an zril aliquando signiferumque, ea sea volutpat definitiones. Vis ut dicat ludus.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>          
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="block" id = "phone">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img class="handle" id = "phoneimg" src = "phone.png" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h3> Phone </h3>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei option sapientem his, vide mucius fuisset mea id. Te novum consulatu nam, vim cu postea delectus. Nam an zril aliquando signiferumque, ea sea volutpat definitiones. Vis ut dicat ludus.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

         </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $thisBlock = $(this).closest('.block');

        $('.block').css('opacity', 0);

        $thisBlock.css({
            'opacity': 1,
            'left': '100',
        });
    });
});
```